# Как отключить звуковой сигнал, появляющийся перед воспроизведением музыкальной композиции?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qmediaplayer, qtmultimedia

Мой небольшой код создает кнопку `play_btn` на главном окне приложения. Эта кнопка связана с методом `play_song()` класса `MyWindow`. 
Метод `play_song()` задает проигрывателю источник для воспроизведения. В данном случае источником является первый элемент списка `self.list`, в которым хранятся пути к mp3-файлам.

**Клик на кнопку `play_btn` действительно запускает проигрывание композиции, но перед этим появляется короткий электронный звук.** Этот звук не зависит от аудиофайла, который будет проигрываться. 
Как я понял, он не является багом и появляется специально, возможно, для оповещения пользователя о начале проигрывания. 
**Мне бы очень хотелось отключить его.** Есть ли способ сделать это?

---

**UPD:**

Я забыл сказать, что звук появляется не перед любым mp3-файлом. Есть песни, которые начинают воспроизводиться молча. Я не думаю, что некоторые из них могут быть бракованными. В других проигрывателях все из них читаются хорошо.
Наверное, это делу не поможет, но нужно добавить, что большинство mp3-файлов посредством модуля *PyQt5* у меня отказывались воспроизводиться, но были и те, что воспроизводились. Тогда я установил какой-то пак кодеков *K-Lite*, ситуация поправилась (моя операционная система - *Windows 10*, самая обычная сборка). Так вот, файлы, которым были необходимы кодеки, проигрываются без этого звука. Файлы, которые воспроизводились без кодеков, вызывают перед проигрыванием этот электронный звук.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtMultimedia

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # self.list = ['8.Figure09.mp3', '13.Numb.mp3']
        self.list = ['bibi.mp3', 'D:/_Qt/EXE/Mp3/new_build/QThread_mp3/img/zvuki_prirody.mp3']

        self.player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()

        self.box = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)      

        play_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Play', clicked = self.play_song)
        self.box.addWidget(play_btn, 0, 0)

    # Воспроизведение
    def play_song(self, song):
        self.player.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl(self.list[0])))
        self.player.play()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle('MP3-player, PyQt5')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Мой слух далек от музыкального. 
Видимо поэтому я не слышу никаких помех, о которых вы говорите. 
Попробуйте на другом пк.

Comment: @S.Nick Звук очень громкий, поэтому это не помехи:) Я обновил вопрос, где рассказал о некоторых деталях. Думаю, что дело в них

Comment: @S.Nick другой компьютер выдает ошибку. Это значит, что ему необходимы кодеки. Файлы, которым не нужны эти кодеки, играются без этого странного звука вначале. Все, что я пытаюсь воспроизвести, является обычными MP3-файлами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня не было нужды устанавливать какие-то пак кодеки.

Основываясь на своем предыдущем ответе,
я вам предлагаю проверить следующую идею,
суть которой заключается в установлении позиции воспроизведения.

Значение позиции я добавил в `self.list`, 
один файл проигрываем с самого начала,
а другой с позиции воспроизведения 20000 milliseconds.

Вставьте для своих сломанных файлов примерное количество milliseconds,
которое длится этот электронный звук.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtMultimedia

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
#        self.list = ['1.Papercut.mp3', '13.Numb.mp3']
#        self.list = ['bibi.mp3', 'D:/_Qt/EXE/Mp3/new_build/QThread_mp3/img/zvuki_prirody.mp3']

        self.list = {
            'bibi.mp3': [1, ],                                                       #     1
            'D:/_Qt/EXE/Mp3/new_build/QThread_mp3/img/zvuki_prirody.mp3': [20000, ]  # 20000
        }
        self.song = ''                                                            
        self.player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
        self.box = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)      

        for line, song in enumerate(self.list):
            play_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Play', clicked=lambda ch, song=song: self.play(song))
            pause_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Pause', clicked=self.pause, enabled=False) 
            label = QtWidgets.QLabel(song)
            self.box.addWidget(play_btn, line, 0)
            self.box.addWidget(pause_btn, line, 1)
            self.box.addWidget(label, line, 2)
            self.list[song].append(play_btn)       
            self.list[song].append(pause_btn)      

    # Воспроизведение
    def play(self, song):
        if self.player.isAudioAvailable() == False:
            self.player.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl(song)))
            self.list[song][2].setEnabled(True)                                    # [2]
            self.song = song 
            self.player.setPosition(self.list[song][0])                            # + setPosition

        if self.song == song:
            pass
        else:
            self.player.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl(song)))
            self.list[self.song][2].setEnabled(False)                              # [2]
            self.list[song][2].setEnabled(True)                                    # [2]
            self.song = song

            # self.list[song][0] - это текущая позиция воспроизведения, 
            # выраженная в миллисекундах с начала мультимедиа.            
            self.player.setPosition(self.list[song][0])                            # + setPosition

        self.player.play()

        # duration - Это свойство содержит продолжительность текущего медиа.         
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(200, lambda: print(f'duration -> {self.player.duration()}')) # +++
        # position - Это свойство содержит позицию воспроизведения текущего носителя.
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(200, lambda: print(f'position -> {self.player.position()}')) # +++

    # Пауза
    def pause(self):
        self.player.pause()

    # Повтор
    def replay(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle('MP3-player, PyQt5')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хватает 5 миллисекунд, спасибо:) Придется как-то выставлять это для всех файлов, т.к. я не могу знать даже их примерное количество. Да и файлы, мне кажется, не сломанные. Я видел в гугле, что не у одного меня такие проблемы, но про этот звук никто ничего не говорил. Раньше я думал, что он связан с PyQt5, но теперь убежден, что виноваты исключительно кодеки

Comment: Я же говорил, что пытаюсь написать простенький музыкальный плеер. Никогда не думал, что возникнут проблемы с воспроизведением звука. Не очень плеер получается, который не воспроизводит половину аудиозаписей:(